# jquery-ui-rails gem doesn't work on preexisting project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, rubygems, slider, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm using the jquery-ui-rails gem to create a slider, however it does not work on a preexisting project for some odd reason.  If I create a new project (rails new blog), generate a user scaffold, then add gmaps4rails gem and then jquery-ui-rails gem the map and slider work and appear just fine.  However if I open an older project, follow the exact same steps (adding same columns etc), the map will appear fine but the slider will not appear.  Does anyone know why this is/how to fix it?

This is my gemfile in case there are any gems that cause conflicts

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.8'
gem 'mysql2'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
  gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'gmaps4rails'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', :require => "bcrypt"
gem 'mail'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

found the issue, after adding the jquery-rails-ui gem you need to run bundle exec rake assets:precompile in the command line for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you are including jquery-ui-rails *only* in the assets group. The gems in the assets group are only used during asset pipeline operations.

Move jquery-ui-rails outside of the assets group, run 'bundle install', and see if it works.

Comment: I just tried that, then I also tried uninstalling and reinstalling the jquery-ui-rails gem however the slider still refuses to appear.